# How to combine two lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I can write the append line two ways. Neither produce the desired result. Is there a way to wrap this up in 1 line?

Option 1:

```
row.append(x[1] for x in emails if x[0] == row[1])
```

Yields:

```
[['project1', 'email1', <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0227D670>], ['project1', 'email2', <generator object <genexpr> at 0x022EB8A0>]]
```

Option 2:

```
row.append([x[1] for x in emails if x[0] == row[1]])
```

Yields:

```
[['project1', 'email1', ['john@gmail.com']], ['project1', 'email2', ['bill@gmail.com']]]
```

Desired Result:

```
[['project1', 'email1', 'john@gmail.com'], ['project1', 'email2', 'bill@gmail.com']]
```

Code:

```
emails = [['email1','john@gmail.com'],['email2','bill@gmail.com']]

projects = [['project1', 'email1'], ['project1', 'email2']]

for row in projects:
    row.append(x[1] for x in emails if x[0] == row[1])
print projects
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your existing code, replace this one line:

```
row.append(x[1] for x in emails if x[0] == row[1])
```

With:

```
row.extend(x[1] for x in emails if x[0] == row[1])
```

#### One-line solution

Alternatively, eliminating the loop and condensing the code all into one line:

```
>>> projects = [  row + [x[1] for x in emails if x[0] == row[1]] for row in projects ]
>>> print projects 
[['project1', 'email1', 'john@gmail.com'], ['project1', 'email2', 'bill@gmail.com']]
```

Comment: using a list to pass to extend is not needed, a generator expression can be used.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Good suggestion.  Updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
emails = [['email1','john@gmail.com'],['email2','bill@gmail.com']]

projects = [['project1', 'email1'], ['project1', 'email2']]
from itertools import chain


print([list(set((chain.from_iterable(ele)))) for ele in zip(emails,projects)])
[['email1', 'john@gmail.com', 'project1'], ['email2', 'project1', 'bill@gmail.com']]
```

Or:

```
print([list(set(ele).union(projects[ind])) for ind, ele in enumerate(emails)])
```

Or:

```
print([projects[ind] + [ele for ele in sub if ele not in projects[ind]] for ind, sub in enumerate(emails)])
```

All the different versions will work for multiple items not just checking against a single element.